# Display query results using pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have the below query which i to display the results using a PIVOT so that the results are displayed in one row.

```
With T1 As
    (EXT Code
    ),

T2 AS (
    SELECT p.SId, p.TransType, Amount =SUM(p.Amount)
    FROM T1 p
    GROUP BY p.SId, p.TransType
)

SELECT m.SNo, m.Name, t.TransType,

    CASE WHEN t.TransType ='PAYCM' THEN t.Amount ELSE 0 END  AS 'GROSS CM',
    CASE WHEN t.TransType ='PAYYTD' THEN t.Amount ELSE 0 END AS 'GROSS YTD',
    CASE WHEN t.TransType ='TAXCM' THEN t.Amount ELSE 0 END AS 'Tax CM',
    CASE WHEN t.TransType ='TAXYTD' THEN t.Amount ELSE 0 END AS 'Tax YTD'
FROM Master m INNER JOIN T2 t ON t.PId = m.Id
```

Comment: What is your question?  Sample data and desired results would  help.

Comment: What is your current and expected output?

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Currently running SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

If you want one row, then use aggregation and remove the non-aggregated columns:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN t.TransType = 'PAYCM' THEN t.Amount ELSE 0 END)  AS GROSS _CM,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.TransType = 'PAYYTD' THEN t.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS GROSS_YTD,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.TransType = 'TAXCM' THEN t.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Tax_CM,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.TransType = 'TAXYTD' THEN t.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Tax_YTD
FROM Master m INNER JOIN
     T2 t
     ON t.PId = m.Id;
```

Comment: Tried the above solution but still getting the same results